# basic JSON pulling data help

Tags: php, json, object, oop

New to json data and struggling i guess the answer is real easy but been bugging me for the last hour..

Sample data

```
    {
   "data": 
      {
         "userid": "17",
         "dates": {
            "timestame": "1275528578",
                  },
         "username": "harino54",

      }

}
```

Ok I can pull userid or username easy enough with

```
echo "$t->userid" or echo "$t->username "
```

but how do I pull data from the brackets within ? in this case timestame?

cant seem to figure it out..

any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you are looking for something like this: `echo "{$t->dates->timestame}";`.

To access data from an object within quotes, you need to surround it with braces.

alternately, you could just say: `echo $t->date->timestame;` without the quotes.

Are you doing someting like this?

```
$t = json_decode($jsonString);
echo $t->data->dates->timestame;
```

or

```
$t = json_decode($jsonString);
echo "{$t->data->dates->timestame}";
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$t -> dates -> timestame
```

Comment: Is that because of the spelling discrepancy (timestamp vs timestame)?

Comment: @JustinStolle: No. It's because the asker has it in a string. Outside of a string it works perfectly.